# Java2D / Graphics2D performance

Tags: java, performance, awt, java-2d

Maybe there's someone out there who has spent time on this. I'm working on a graph visualization lib in Java and I just did some performance tests.

When I'm adding about 2000 vertices connected by 1000 - 3000 edges, it gets really, really slow. There are tools out there doing way better ([gephi](http://gephi.org/) for example).. How do they do it? Isn't Java2D hardware accelerated by default? Do I have to use some OpenGL lib?

I'm drawing the graphs inside a JComponent which gets redrawn by a timer every few milliseconds (doesn't really matter, if I give it 100 ms or 1 ms, it stays really slow).

Is my approach flawed or shouldn't I use Java2D for this?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Have you formally profiled your code so that you know for a fact that the rendering is your bottle neck? If not, I'd do this as a first step.

Comment: never redraw everything. it is impossible. cache whatever you can.

Comment: @Hovecraft: I'll do this as soon as I'm back on Monday.

Comment: @ J-16: How should I cache something, when everything is moving and visible? E.g. being placed / moved by a force directed layout algorithm

Comment: Are you using `VolatileImage`?

Comment: Try it. `BufferedImage` isn't hardware-accelerated afaik, while `VolatileImage` is (if available).

Answer (score 0):

As Torious suggested you probably want to use a [VolatileImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/VolatileImage.html) if you are working in Java2D to get the benefits of hardware acceleration.

However - If you want absolute best performance, you are probably better off going for an OpenGL - based solution.

LWJGL ( http://lwjgl.org/ ) is designed for games but allows you to use pretty much all the relevant OpenGL functionality so is pretty good for visualisation as well. Might be worth giving it a try!